# FedEx Web Service Testing

Tags: web-services, integration-testing, fedex

When using the developer mode of FedEx Freight Rate how do I test with a real client account so that I can use a shipping address that reflects the client's location and see results that accurately reflect discounts that may be applied?

It seems that in test mode I can only use the billing address provided when by FedEx when I requested my keys.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to test with live/real accounts in the FedEx test environment.

If your only seeking rate quotes (and not generating labels and/or bill of ladings) then my suggestion would be to just use their production environment since rate quotes are considered a 'read-only' transaction and don't require any special certification.